# How to remove a word from TFS task list dictionary

Tags: dictionary, visual-studio-2013, internet-explorer-11

I was working on a TFS task list and right-clicked to add a word to the dictionary by mistake.

How do I remove it?

This is internet explorer 11, with a Visual Studio 2013 version of TFS.

Thanks.

Comment: TFS doesn't have a dictionary, and I'm not sure what part of TFS you were using when you added it too. I'd guess this is part of your browser or some extension you're using.

Comment: Never heard task list in TFS. Did you mean the task workitem ? Suggest you to provide a screenshot to make the question more clear.

Comment: Can't provide much of a screenshot for proprietary reasons.

Comment: @DaveShaw, please promote your comment to an answer, and I will duly mark it as such.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS doesn't have a dictionary, and I'm not sure what part of TFS you were using when you added it too. I've not seen a "Task List".

This will be part of your browser or some extension you're using.